# Chrome extension - result is always null

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've just started playing with Chrome extensions.

In my content.js I have following

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("", function(response){
    //some logic
});
```

And in background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
   sendResponse(someFunction);
   return true;
});

function someFunction(para) {
    //logic
}
```

The issue is, the `response` in content.js is always undefined... The similar posts on this site is usually due to asynchronous calls such as ajax, but I'm not doing anything asynchronously and I'm returning true which according to the docs returns the method... I can only assume my logic is some how backwards?

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Remove the brackets - it's just: `AddToBody parent`. Or use `Call` like this: `Call AddToBody(parent)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant send a function ("someFunction") as a response. the response object must be serializable.

Comment: This is the answr. I understand now. I can't return a function... I was hoping to use the response as a callback but this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: im not sure im following your idea. your function is already calling back. why whould you need a callback? thats why you are using messaging.